# How to overcome the error NoSuchFieldError: PATCH

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have crated a project using spring mvc which includes hibernate and jpa. When i try to run that program got an error. Please help. Thank you.

Exception :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
```

Root Cause :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PATCH
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:808)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: did you compile your web app against a different version of spring loaded at runtime?

Comment: i have used vmware spring to compile and run.. my application has build successfully when i run maven install

Answer (score 0):

Did you mark your spring dependency as 'provided' on maven, and then run your code on the app server against a different version of spring? If so this is probably the cause

If your app server provides spring library, ensure the declared maven dependency version matches

Answer (score -1):

Even I faced the same problem for first trial with of Spring MVC what I figured out that a Class name `MimeType` was missing (i.e `org.springframework.util.MimeType`) you can solve this by adding `spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar` file.

I think this would solve your problem cause it worked with me.